# Liferay date-input displays wrong date

Tags: date, jsp, java-8, liferay, liferay-7

I'm using Liferay 7.1 I have the following `liferau-ui:input-date` object and I want to pre-select a date:

```
<%
    final LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
%>

<liferay-ui:input-date
    dayValue="<%= today.getDayOfMonth()%>"
    monthValue="<%=today.getMonth().getValue()%>"
    yearValue="<%= today.getYear()%>"
</liferay-ui:input-date>
```

When I output `today`'s values directly on the JSP I get the correct date for today: `3 12 2018`.

When the element is rendered, it has selected the wrong date: `01/03/2019`. There is nothing further documented in the [taglibdocs](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.1-latest/taglibs/util-taglib/liferay-ui/input-date.html) that I think could help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the month value. In Java it's 1-12 with liferay datepicker it's 0-11.
In order to display the correct month i subtracted 1 from month value. It's not an elegant solution but i couldn't find any better way.

```
<liferay-ui:input-date
    dayValue="<%= today.getDayOfMonth()%>"
    monthValue="<%=today.getMonth().getValue() - 1 %>"
    yearValue="<%= today.getYear()%>"
</liferay-ui:input-date>
```

This will render 12/03/2018

Comment: The year is still wrong however, and so is the day... it should be the 4th of December 2018! I guess there are more off-by-ones in the Liferay code

Comment: Sorry i missed that. I guess it automatically changed to 2019 because December plus one is January, so it's a new year. Please try it with my month value and tell me if the year is still an issue. Otherwise i will edit my answer to 2018 to avoid any confusion :D

Comment: It works indeed! Many thanks. It was the MM/DD/YYYY format that confused me. Guess what my next question is gonna be...